# SQL query - select only products ids which was sorted top in another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, sql-order-by

Ok, I have situation where I need to create SQL query which will return for me ids from table1 (`products`) which was ordered by table2 (`category`) and limited by 10 for each category.

So, what I need. Select product ids which was appeared on "top 10" (limited by 10) results in each category after ordering of those products. Each product has some columns and I order by those columns. The same product can appear on different categories on top 10, for example. So I need use `distinct` for uniq results.

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any relationship between Product and Category? What at the Product columns you're ordering by? Is it ok for there to be duplication between different lists of products? You should really post you models/sql tables and more clearly explain what you're trying to do if you want real help.

Assuming they're many-to-many/the relationships are set up in rails and having the same products in multiple lists is ok I would do something like this

```
top_products = {}
Category.all.each do |cat|
  top_products[cat.name] = cat.products.order("some_product_column DESC").limit(10).map{|p| p.id}
end
```